# Cardinality of partial orders on $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let the set $A$ be defined: $A=\{X \subseteq \mathbb R \times \mathbb R: X$ is a partial order $\land \max X \in \mathbb Z \land min X \in \mathbb Z \}$

What's the cardinality of $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Pick any partial order on $\Bbb R\setminus\{0,1\}$ and declare that $0$ is the new minimum and $1$ is the new maximum. How many ways do you have to define partial orders on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: There are $\aleph$ ways? I don't actually know, just a guess...

Comment: Instead of guessing, try to prove that (but you can't). Here's a hint that might help you on your way. Take a set of real numbers, there's an order which is trivial on that set, and linear on its complement.