# Cardinality of all partial orders on $\Bbb Z$ disjoint from the standard order $<$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

> What is the cardinality of all partial orders on $\Bbb Z$ disjoint from the standard order $<$?

**My attempt:**

Let $S:=\{\prec\in\mathcal P(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z)\mid \prec\text{ is a partial order and } <\cap\prec\space =\emptyset\space\}.$ I claim $\operatorname{card}(S)=\mathfrak c.$

$\boxed{\leq}:$ Since $S\subseteq\mathcal P(\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z),\operatorname{card}(S)\le\mathfrak c.$

$\boxed{\geq}:$ Let's define $\Phi:\mathcal P(\Bbb Z)\to S,\Phi: A\mapsto\Phi(A),$

$$\Phi(A):=\space >\cap (\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\setminus\{(x,y)\mid x\in A\lor y\in A\}).$$

The idea I'm trying to build my answer upon was taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/842740) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4441318/721644), but I would like to try to elaborate on it and *ask* if I got it right while I'm preparing for my exam.

Since $\Phi(A)\subseteq>,\Phi(A)$ is irreflexive and also disjoint from $<.$

Suppose $x\Phi(A)y\land y\Phi(A)z.$ Then $x>y>z$ and $x,y,z\in\Bbb Z\setminus A,$ so $x>z$ and $x,z\in\Bbb Z\setminus A,$ which means $x\Phi(A)z.$ Therefore, $\Phi(A)$ is transitive.

It follows $\Phi(A)\in S,$ i. e., the map $\Phi:\mathcal P(\Bbb Z)\to S$ is well-defined.
Since:

1. each $x\in A$ is incomparable to any other $y\in\Bbb Z,$ each $x\in A$ is both minimal and maximal.
2. $(\Bbb Z\setminus A,>)$ is totally ordered and has neither a minimum nor a maximum,

$A$ is the set of all minimal and all maximum elements of $(\Bbb Z\setminus A,>).$

Suppose $\Phi(A)=\Phi(B)$ for some $A,B\in\mathcal P(\Bbb Z).$ Then $$\begin{aligned}\color{white}=&(x,y)\in\Phi(A)\iff (x,y)\in\Phi (B)\\\implies &x,y\in\Bbb Z\setminus A\iff x,y\in\Bbb Z\setminus B\\\implies& A=B,\end{aligned}$$

so $\Phi:\mathcal P(\Bbb Z)\to S,$ is injective, therefore $\operatorname{card}(S)\ge\mathfrak c.$

Finally, $\operatorname{card}(S)=\mathfrak c.$

Is there anything I should improve or fix?

Comment: Very nice idea behind your proof! Personally, I'm not a huge fan of writing relations as a set - I'd write "for each $A \subseteq \Bbb Z$, define $\prec_A$ by $x \prec_A y$ iff $x, y \notin A$ and $x > y$" (I find this much clearer). If I was working with pen and paper I'd even draw a little Hasse diagram to illustrate the relation I mean (and why it's obviously a partial order). This diagram might also help you find where you made a small mistake... $\Bbb Z \setminus A$ *can* have a minimal maximal element. But this only happens countably often, so the calculation still works.

Comment: Also I assume you meant "$A$ is the set of all minimal maximal elements of $(\Bbb Z, \prec_A) = (\Bbb Z, \Phi(A))$."

Comment: Thank you (for reading too)! I think I meant what you wrote